# Cython Numpy Extension compilation fails with newer versions

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cythonize

A few months ago I wrote [this skeleton package](https://github.com/GjjvdBurg/NumPy_C_Extension/tree/acadd6e3ca842b75d1b8a5b0763a46ddf42ed462) for linking a C library to Python using NumPy and Cython. When I created it compilation worked fine and I was able to use the C code from Python.

However it now seems that my Python, Cython, or NumPy versions have changed in a way that the package won't compile anymore. Was there an API change in one of these packages that I'm not aware of? My `.pxd` header file isn't found and I get a number of compilation errors regarding the use of `with nogil`, such as:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef long total
    cdef long n = x.shape[0]

    # If we want to use "nogil", we have to use "x.data", not "x".
    with nogil:
        total = sum_array(x.data, n)
                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

src/cython_wrapper.pyx:32:25: Coercion from Python not allowed without the GIL
```

But **importantly** these errors don't occur with the previous versions of Cython (0.27.1) and NumPy (1.13.3).

Here are the steps to reproduce this:

#### Old Environment

```sh
virtualenv -p python3.6 old
cd old
source bin/activate
pip install cython==0.27.1 numpy==1.13.3
git clone https://github.com/GjjvdBurg/NumPy_C_Extension
cd NumPy_C_Extension
rm src/cython_wrapper.c
python setup.py build_ext -i
# Compilation proceeds without errors
```

#### New Environment

```sh
virtualenv -p python3.6 new
cd new
source bin/activate
pip install cython==0.28.3 numpy==1.14.5
git clone https://github.com/GjjvdBurg/NumPy_C_Extension
cd NumPy_C_Extension
rm src/cython_wrapper.c
python setup.py build_ext -i
# Compilation fails
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would help to see a minimal example in the question and also to see the actual error message.

Comment: The linked skeleton package **is** the minimal working example (it's only 52 lines of code). I've added one of the compilation errors, but this is **not** the problem, the problem is that compilation fails with new versions but worked before.

Comment: I would only care about the first error - everything else can be spurious. btw  there are only 100 lines in the setup-file alone, which very well could be the culprit here.

Comment: I agree, the first error is that the ``cython_wrapper.pxd`` file can't be found, even though it's in the same directory as the ``cython_wrapper.pyx`` file.

Comment: This looks like a regression and was introduced 0.27.3->0.28.0. It builds when you use `cythonize src/cython_wrapper.pyx` but not with setup.py. Best thing would be to report it to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues

Comment: Thanks @ead, I've posted an issue [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2452)